# How to delete "dev3" name when packing with python & pbr

Tags: python, package, python-pbr

I want to build my pack, but when I executing "python setup.py build sdist", it packed a package which named "xxx-1.0.0.dev3"

I do not want the "dev3", but I don't know how to fix it.

And, I use pbr for packing.

Here is setup.py:

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    setup_requires=['pbr'],
    pbr=True)
```

Here is setup.cfg:

```
[metadata]
Version=1.0.0
name=noni
author=xxx
author-email=xxxx
summary=...
license=MIT
description-file =
    README.rst
home-page = xxxx
requires-python = >=2.7
classifier =
    Development Status :: 4 - Beta
    Environment :: Console
    Intended Audience :: Developers
    Intended Audience :: Information Technology
    License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License
    Operating System :: OS Independent
    Programming Lauguage :: python

[files]
packages =
    xxx
data-files =
    etc/pbr = etc/pbr/*
```

Comment: It didn't work. Am I add a the wrong "relevant" tag ? here is my new setup.cfg:  `[metadata]
version=1.0.0
relevant =
name=noni
author=Allen.Wu
author-email=allenlikeu@gmail.com
summary=...
license=MIT
description-file =
    README.rst
home-page = https://github.com/Allen5/noni
requires-python = >=2.7
classifier =
    Development Status :: 4 - Beta
    Environment :: Console
    Intended Audience :: Developers
    Intended Audience :: Information Technology

[files]
packages =
    noni
data-files =
    etc/pbr = etc/pbr/*`

Comment: If you use a setuptools_scm for versioning, this happens because you made changes since the last tag; see their description here under "Default versioning scheme" https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/1.15.0rc1/

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that if you add a tag with your version number to the current commit the package will build with dev suffix.

This is based on the practice that any release is tagged. If is not tagged is probably a development build which is numbered with the `devN` suffix where N is the number of commits since the last tag.

Comment: But what if I want to test uploading the package to test-pypi and that this is done *before* I make a release (and therefore tag)? The current behavior is that a `.devXX` version will be uploaded and any installations that I want to test of other packages that require my package will fail since the version is different (because of the dev part)